# Approximate the Fransén-Robinson constant

Tags: code-golf, calculus, approximation

Given an input `n`, output the value of the [Fransén-Robinson constant](https://oeis.org/A058655) with `n` digits after the decimal place, with rounding.

## Rules

- You may assume that all inputs are integers between 1 and 60.
- You may not store any related values - the constant must be calculated, not recalled.
- Rounding must be done with the following criteria:

  - If the digit following the final digit is less than five, the final digit must remain the same.
  - If the digit following the final digit is greater than or equal to five, the final digit must be incremented by one.
- You must only output the first `n+1` digits.
- Standard loopholes apply.

## Test Cases

```
>>> f(0)
3

>>> f(1)
2.8

>>> f(11)
2.80777024203

>>> f(50)
2.80777024202851936522150118655777293230808592093020

>>> f(59)
2.80777024202851936522150118655777293230808592093019829122005

>>> f(60)
2.807770242028519365221501186557772932308085920930198291220055
```

Comment: What if you do not have support for arbitrary precision floats?

Comment: @flawr I suppose that the language would have to use some form of string concatenation or similar. Otherwise, it may not be the language for this challenge.

Comment: Too bad, that basically only leaves us with hardcoding the numbers. PS: Why don't you add `f(60)` to the test cases? That way participants wouldn't have to fetch it externally=)

Comment: @flawr Hardcoding is disallowed by rule 2.

Comment: Are trailing zeroes ok?

Comment: @Mego I would say "no", due to rule 4, but trailing zeroes don't seem like a problem very much, since it's still the same value. They're fine.

Comment: Shouldn't `f(59)` end with a `6`, because of rounding?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere - only if f(60) was rounded down. If f(61) ended with ....200549, then f(59) rounds down to end with a 5.

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE: Has it been two weeks *yet*? You may be able to see I love to complain.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Oh, whoops, sorry. I haven't been around much recently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Mathematica, <s>44</s> <s>39</s> <s>36</s> 25 UTF-8 bytes

- *-5 bytes thanks to Sp3000*
- *-3 bytes thanks to kennytm*
- *-11 bytes thanks to senegrom*

Crossed out <s>44</s> is still regular 44!!

```
N[∫1/x!{x,-1,∞},#+1]&
```

Example:

```
f=N[∫1/x!{x,-1,∞},#+1]&
f[2]
```

Outputs `2.81`.

Explanation

```
N[               , # + 1] 
  ∫1/x!{x,-1,∞}
```

First step takes `N`umeric of the rest, with `#` (first parameter) + 1 precision. `!` (factorial) does what you'd expect. `{x, -1, Infinity}` sets the bounds for the (strangely formatted) Integral.

Comment: I can't test this, so I assume this rounds correctly?

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE I checked for `n = 60`, it rounds correctly. (The `61`st digit is an `8`). You can look at Wolfram's docs for `N`.

Comment: Coolio. Just checking.

Comment: You can probably use a literal `∞` in place of `Infinity`. I'd suggest dividing by 0, if that didn't produce `ComplexInfinity` instead...

Comment: @Sp3000 How would dividing by 0 save any bytes? (Note: `Head[1/0]@1 == Infinity`)

Comment: @LegionMammal978 It wouldn't have saved any over `∞` even if it did return `Infinity`, but it'd have been an amusing alternative.

Comment: `Gamma[x]` can be replaced by `(x-1)!`. And then you could change to `x!` by integrating in `{x,-1,∞}`.

Comment: I think the integration could be shortened by using the literal ∫ in UTF-8

Comment: @senegrom I tried that, but it doesn't work. How do you suggest using it?

Comment: try `N[∫1/x!{x,-1,∞},#+1]&` where `` is Unicode-F74C; displays as `` in Mathematica. (note that the space before `&` is also not necessary...)